# How do I get the active response in a Google Apps Script bound to a form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm writing a script within (bound to) a Google Form. The idea here is to have the respondent enter their email address in the form (that's the only field in the form) and then make a copy of a spreadsheet (based on a template) and email it to them.

The script is triggered by the submission of the form. At the moment I'm wondering what the easiest way would be to grab that email address out of their response. I have gotten as far as figuring out that it's available within `FormApp.getActiveForm()`, but I can't seem to find a "`getActiveResponse()`" method. How do I grab that email address they just entered, without scrolling through every response? If there was a `getActiveResponse`, then I would just grab the contents of Item 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Form submit event has the [FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) property. This property has the method [getRespondentEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getRespondentEmail())

If the script is triggered by the submit event, you should be able to fetch the email address from there.

Comment: Hi Jasper, according to the documentation, that built-in email address collection capability is restricted to Google accounts. This form might be used by people who don't have a Google account. So I would like to have them enter their email address (via the form) and then I would like to retrieve it. Thanks.

Comment: True, in that case use getResponseForItem(item). It is also a method of the FormResponse. item would be the item on the form. Or loop trough the items with getItemResponses(). The key is to use the FormResponse object.

Comment: getResponseForItem(item) is a method of the FormResponse class, which means I have to have the response that I want to get the item for. My trouble is that I don't know how to get the response itself, once I have that I can use the getResponseForItem method.

Comment: The FormResponse can be retrieved using a Trigger. The Trigger is fired when the form is submitted. Then the FormResponse contains the submitted form. The form submit trigger is described on this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: YES! That did it. Perfect. Thank you!!

Comment: I'll mention exactly what I did

Comment: Hmmm. Can't seem to figure out how to edit these posts. So I guess this will have to be one long paragraph. So, I had a function onFormSubmit, and I had set it up to trigger (using the Resources menu) when the form submits. The function wasn't set up to take any arguments. After reading the info linked by JD, I added an argument e to my function, and now I can access e.response which is the form response! Voila!